# Get Filtered and associated records in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

### **I have three Database Tables.**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblprojecttype` (
  `ProjectTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectType` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `IsActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `tblprojecttypecurrencyprice` (
  `ProjectTypeCurrencyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CurrencyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Price` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `tblcurrency` (
  `CurrencyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Currency` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `IsActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

### **Models**

```
class Currency_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblcurrency";
    protected $primaryKey = "CurrencyID";
    public $timestamps = false;
}

class ProjectType_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblprojecttype";
    protected $primaryKey = "ProjectTypeID";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function projecttypecurrencyprice()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('\App\Models\ProjectTypeCurrencyPrice_Model', 
                                                     "ProjectTypeID");
    }
}

class ProjectTypeCurrencyPrice_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblprojecttypecurrencyprice";
    protected $primaryKey = "ProjectTypeCurrencyID";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function Currency()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Currency_Model', "CurrencyID");
    }
}
```

**There is `CurrencyID` relationship and `ProjectTypeID` relationship**

### **What I am trying ?**

In my Laravel 5.1 code, I am trying to achive below sql statement so that I can get `projecttypecurrencyprice records` for each `ProjectType record`. Finally it should also show records from `currency Table` for each  `projecttypecurrencyprice`  record

```
$ProjectTypes = \App\Models\project\ProjectType\ProjectType_Model
                ::with("projecttypecurrencyprice")
                ->with("projecttypecurrencyprice.Currency")
                ->get();
```

### **What's the Problem ?**

I am getting all Currency records for each `projecttypecurrencyprice` record. I just want those where currency ID = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply additional criteria when fetching related ** projecttypecurrencyprice** objects. You can do that with **whereHas()** method. The following code should do the trick:

```
$ProjectTypes = \App\Models\project\ProjectType\ProjectType_Model
  ::with("projecttypecurrencyprice")
  ->with(["projecttypecurrencyprice.Currency" => function($query) {
    $query->where('CurrencyID', 1);
  }])
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not missing something, shouldn't a simple [where() clause in your eloquent query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) do the trick?

Like this:

```
$ProjectTypes = \App\Models\project\ProjectType\ProjectType_Model
            ::with("projecttypecurrencyprice")
            ->with("projecttypecurrencyprice.Currency")
            ->where('id', 1)
            ->get();
```

(not tested of course, please don't slap me)

Comment: This will apply the constraint on ProjectType_Model, while OP wants to have it applied on projecttypecurrencyprice.Currency.